Echarts4r in programmatically created tabsets in quarto not rendering?
Taking the example in this How to programmatically generate tabset-panel in quarto?, I have established rendering charts in dynamically rendered tabsets.
I am hoping to replace the ggplots with interactive echarts, which work independently of the quarto document.
See below code:
---
title: "Panel tabs"
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    
---

```{r echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

data <- iris

species <- list()

for(i in unique(data$Species)){
  
  species[[paste(i)]] <- data %>%
    filter(Species == i) %>%
    e_charts(Sepal.Length)  %>%
    e_line(Sepal.Width)
  
  
  # species[[paste(i)]] <- data %>%
  #   filter(Species == i) %>%
  #   ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  #   geom_point() +
  #   theme_bw(base_size = 18)
  #   
  # 
  # 
  # species[[paste(i)]] <- data %>%
  #   filter(Species == i) %>%
  #   plotly::plot_ly(x = ~ Sepal.Length, y = ~ Sepal.Width)
  
  
  
}

```

# Iris Plots 

::: {.panel-tabset}


```{r}
#| results: asis
#| fig-width: 14
#| fig-height: 6

iwalk(species, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  
  print(.x)
  
  cat('\n\n')
  
})

```
:::


This quarto document in rendered via a download handler on a shiny app, but either rendering this way or directly through the qmd does not work.
I've commented out the ggplot2 code which works. When I try to render echarts4r, the code either doesn't render at all or returns the html composition of the Echart. I suspect this is related to the cat() functionality, but cannot find a solution (or whether there is one). Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Does it work without embed-resources: true?

It doesn't unfortunately, still has the issue of missing plots

Since you are generating the output asis, you need the underlying HTML code for the E-charts. print method for htmltools::tagList())  will help you in this regard. And also you need to make sure all the JS dependencies of E-charts are loaded and hence you need a dummy E-chart graph.
---
title: "Panel tabs"
format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false

library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)

data <- iris

species <- list()

for(i in unique(data$Species)) {
  species[[paste(i)]] <- data %>%
    filter(Species == i) %>%
    e_charts(Sepal.Length)  %>%
    e_line(Sepal.Width)
}

```

# Iris Plots 

```{r}
#| include: false

# This is a dummy chart, just to make sure all E-charts' 
# JS dependency are loaded.
e_chart()
```

::: {.panel-tabset}

```{r}
#| results: asis

iwalk(species, ~ {
  cat('## ', .y, '\n\n')
  print(htmltools::tagList(.x))
  cat('\n\n')
})

```
:::


Really nice answer, worked a treat! Any context as to why you need to initiate JS after we've made the echarts in the previous R chunk?

@Ben_Kimpton, Well technically we haven't plotted any echarts plot until the iwalk part, we have stored them in an object. We just need to make sure that the js deps are loaded before we actually plot echarts graphs.

Could go into a whole new rabbit hole as to why that's needed and isn't initiated upon actually plotting the chart. Either way, thank you for insight, much appreciated!
